# migrate-mongo couldn't update document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, migration, migrate-mongo

I am using "migrate-mongo": "^10.0.0" package.

somehow updateOne doesn't work. no error is returning however document is not updating:

```
module.exports = {
  async up(db, client) {
    db.collection("users").updateOne(
      { _id: "63918aa70e345d3c60b740c3" },
      { $set: { promotedAt: 1234567890 } }
    );
  },

  async down(db, client) {
    db.collection("users").updateOne(
      { _id: "63918aa70e345d3c60b740c3" },
      { $set: { promotedAt: null } }
    );
  },
};
```

what am I doing wrong?

ChatGPT is no use :((

updateMany method working properly

Comment: You'll need to provide more details around what "doesn't work" means in this context. For example, is the command erroring? If so, what's the error? If not, what is the response from the database for the command(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "doesn't work" means doesn't return an error but also doesn't update the document, this is most likely a type mismatch.

`"63918aa70e345d3c60b740c3"` is a string while the default type of the _id field is ObjectId.

Since MQL operators are type-sensitive, you will need to convert that in order for the query to match, perhaps with something like `ObjectId("63918aa70e345d3c60b740c3")`.

Answer (score 0):

use this npm package to upgrade mongoose version. it provides supported for all older functions in earlier version of mongo by wrapping each functions.

[mongoose-legacy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-legacy)

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Answer (score 0):

There was a wrong URL provided in the `migrate-mongo-config.js` file